# Alternative to Task.Run that doesn't throw warning

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient

The following code works as I want it to, but causes a warning:

`Warning   1   Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`

Is there an alternative to `Task.Run()` that will kick off this thread in a nice terse way?

```
/// <summary>
/// StartSubscriptionsAsync must be called if you want subscription change notifications.
/// This starts the subscription engine. We always create one subscription for
/// Home DisplayName to start (but ignore any updates).
/// </summary>
public async Task StartSubscriptionsAsync(){
    await _subscriptionClient.ConnectAsync(Host, Port);

    // Generates a compiler warning, but it is what we want
    Task.Run(() => ReadSubscriptionResponses());

    // We do a GetValue so we know we have a good connection
    SendRequest("sys://Home?f??" + "Name");

    if (FastMode) EnableFastMode();

    foreach (var subscription in _subscriptions) {
        SendSubscriptionRequest(subscription.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always disable the warning in this place by wrapping the code block in `#pragma warning disable/enable` (I don't remember the warning code now though, sorry)...

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873131.aspx It is suggested that you suppress the warning in such cases.

Comment: Closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864367/fire-and-forget-approach

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning is triggered when you neither `await` the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) returned by the [Task.Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx) nor store it to `await` i later. If you want fire-and-forget behavior, you can simply store the task but never `await` it:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => ReadSubscriptionResponses());
```

Comment: Since C# 7 you can use discards: _ = Task.Run(() => ReadSubscriptionResponses());

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want fire-and-forget behavior, you can call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`.

However, make sure you know how you will handle errors from that function.

Answer (score 1):

Also see Stephen Clearys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864616/567000) to the general question of fire-and-forget async operations. His async-void solution is great when you are running in a non-default synchronization context such as WPF or ASP.NET, because any exceptions will automatically be posted back to the synchronization context, so they won't go unobserved.