# Async-Await, exception handling and continuation using TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code for sample console application, but the method specified in Task continuation using `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` never gets called.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int index = 0;
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => NewTask(index), cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default)
                .ContinueWith(HandleException, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);

            // Some code
            // ...

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task NewTask(int index)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
            await Wait();
        }

        private static async Task Wait()
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            throw new Exception("Testing 123");
        }

        private static void HandleException(Task task)
        {
            if (task != null && task.Exception != null)
            {
                var exceptions = task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions;
                if (exceptions != null)
                    foreach (var exception in exceptions)
                        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when an exception is thrown from `Wait()` method, instead of `HandleException(...)` being called, either program crashes or debugger shows an unhandled exception dialog box.

**EDITED:** Return type of `NewTask` method is `Task`.

Comment: Change your code like this: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => NewTask(index), cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap().ContinueWith(HandleException, cts.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);` Note `Unwrap()`, more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Comment: No, don't do this as it only serves to make the calling code more complicated. The asynchronous function should be called directly.

Comment: @AdamRobinson, *"The asynchronous function should be called directly"* - **usually so, but it *really* depends on what you're doing inside the `async` function**. One notable case is when you need to use a non-default task scheduler. Another possible case is when there's a piece of CPU-bound or blocking code at the begging of the `async` method. That's why `Task.Run` understands and unwraps `async` lambdas, and that's why `Task.Unwrap` exists.

Comment: @Noseratio: Certainly in some cases, but not in the case that the OP has presented. This person is clearly trying to learn about the TPL and `async`/`await`, and trying to explain the corner cases here is likely going to cause more confusion than clarity.

Comment: @AdamRobinson, I recon you're right, in which case mixing `async`/`await` and `ContinueWith` is not a good idea at all, as @SephenCleary points out. It's got to be "async all the way down". In case with a console app, the top level handler could do `Task.Wait()` or simply take [some fire-and-forget approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22864367/1768303) if it doesn't care about completion.

Answer (score 4):

By calling `Factory.StartNew`, you're actually creating a task *whose method body just initiates your actual task*, but your actual task has no continuation on it; only the outer, superfluous task (which won't throw an exception) has one.

Additionally, your async function is `async void`. This makes it impossible to add a continuation. I'm going to go one step further and say that *you should never, ever, make a function that's `async void`*. It should always be `async Task`.

If you make that syntax change, your calling syntax is actually simpler:

```
NewTask(index).ContinueWith(HandleException, cts.Token, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

However, bear in mind that cancellation is not something that you get for free; you either need to be passing your token along to other asynchronous tasks that make use of it or you need to be checking it youself (or call `.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`).

As an aside, by convention any function which returns a `Task` or `Task<T>` should have its name end with `Async` (i.e. it should be named `NewTaskAsync`).

Comment: You are creating two tasks: one is the return value of `Task NewTask(int index)`, the other is the return value of your call to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The latter is a useless wrapper over the former. You are attaching your continuation to that wrapper, rather than to the actually useful inner task that might throw an exception.

Comment: Returning void is justified in some cases [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/JJ991977.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> I have the following code for sample console application

I assume you're doing this to learn `async` and `await`. Here's some tips.

- Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Most of the time you *don't* need to execute code on a background thread, but if you do, then use `Task.Run`.
- Don't use `ContinueWith`. Use `await` instead.
- Follow the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).
- Understand that Console applications are *not* a normal use case for asynchronous applications. If you're planning to end up in a UI application, then you should start in a UI application.

For Console apps, just write a `Main` like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MainAsync().Wait();
}
```

And then put your real logic into a real `async` method:

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
{
  ...
}
```

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Got it ... Only thing is, my application is a Windows Service and I need to cancel all ongoing running tasks (downloading files, writing files on Disk) when Windows service is stopped, in which, I set the `CancellationToken` to be cancelled.

Comment: @user1241991: That's a fine approach.

Comment: @user1241991: The `async` and `await` keywords don't really deal with your ability or inability to cancel an operation. You need to pass a `CancellationToken` to your function(s) and actually proactively check it throughout the execution at whatever points would allow you to actually cancel your operation.