# Unnecessary async/await when await is last?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I've been dealing quite a lot with *async await* lately (read every possible article including Stephen's and Jon's last 2 chapters) , but I have come to conclusion and I don't know if it's 100% correct. - hence my question .

Since  `async` only allows the word await to be present , i'll leave `async` aside.

AFAIU  , await is all about continuation . instead of writing functional (continuational) code  , write synchronous code. ( i like to  refer it as *callback'able* code)

So when the compiler reaches `await` - it splits the code to 2 sections and registers the second part to be executed after the first part is done ( *I don't know why the word `callback` isn't used  - which is exactly what is done*). ( meanwhile working - the thread is back doing other things).

But looking at this code :

```
public async  Task ProcessAsync()
        {
           Task<string> workTask = SimulateWork();
           string st= await workTask;
           //do something with st
        }

 public    Task <string> SimulateWork()
        {
            return ...
        }
```

When thread reaches `await workTask;` it split the method to 2 sections . so after `SimulateWork` is finished - the continuation of the method  : AKA : `//do something with st` - is executed.

all ok

**But** what if the method was :

```
public async  Task ProcessAsync()
        {
           Task<string> workTask = SimulateWork();
           await workTask; //i don't care about the result , and I don't have any further commands 
        }
```

Here - I *don't* need continuation  , meaning - I don't need the `await` to split the method which means - I don't need async /await **here at all !**  and still I will have the **same results/behaviour** !

So I could do it like :

```
   public void ProcessAsync()
            {
               SimulateWork();
            }
```

**Question:**

- Was I 100% correct with my diagnostics ?

Comment: To be 100% pure re-write, you should still return `Task` rather than `void` and should return the `Task` returned by `SimulateWork` - that way, the *callers* of `ProcessAsync` can still `await` (or `Wait`) on that `Task` to know when you've finished.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever aside your comment - was my assumption right ?

Comment: You should always care about how tasks complete.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I disagree with this statement. in my sample it will be relevant only if I need to know what happend with `ProcessAsync` . there ARE scenario where fire and forget are legit.

Comment: What will happen if the task ends in error?

Comment: @PauloMorgado When you deal with fire and forget you are less(!) concern about that. on the other hand - if you need ack - then you should use task  + continuewith or await.

Comment: Just like when background thread was executed you would deal with error inside that thread. ( try catch). if it SO important about continuation and A depends on B  - then like I said - use await/continue with

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, you think the `await` below is redundant, as the question's title implies:

```cs
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    Task<string> workTask = SimulateWork();
    await workTask; //i don't care about the result , and I don't have any further 
}
```

First of all, I assume that under *"when `await` is last"* you mean ***"when the `await` is the only `await`*"**. It's got to be that, because otherwise the following simply would not compile:

```cs
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Task<string> workTask = SimulateWork();
    return workTask; 
}
```

Now, if it's the *only* `await`, you can indeed optimize it like this:

```cs
public Task ProcessAsync()
{
    Task<string> workTask = SimulateWork();
    return workTask; 
}
```

However, it would give you completely different exception propagation behavior, which may have some unexpected side effects. The thing is, now exceptions may be thrown on the caller's stack, depending on how `SimulateWork` is internally implemented. I posted a [detailed explanation of this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082631). This normally never happens with `async` `Task`/`Task<>` methods, where exception is stored inside the returned `Task` object. It still may happen for an `async void` method, but that's a [different story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161).

So, if your caller code is ready for such differences in exception propagation, it may be a good idea to skip `async/await` wherever you can and simply return a `Task` instead.

**Another matter is if you want to issue a *fire-and-forget* call**. Usually, you still want to track the status of the fired task somehow, at least for the reason of handling task exceptions. I could not imagine a case where I would really not care if the task never completes, even if all it does is logging.

So, for fire-and-forget I usually use a helper `async void` method which stores the pending task somewhere for later observation, e.g.:

```cs
readonly object _syncLock = new Object();
readonly HashSet<Task> _pendingTasks = new HashSet<Task>();

async void QueueTaskAsync(Task task)
{
    // keep failed/cancelled tasks in the list
    // they will be observed outside
    lock (_syncLock)
        _pendingTasks.Add(task);

    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch
    {
        // is it not task's exception?
        if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
            throw; // re-throw

        // swallow, but do not remove the faulted/cancelled task from _pendingTasks 
        // the error will be observed later, when we process _pendingTasks,
        // e.g.: await Task.WhenAll(_pendingTasks.ToArray())
        return;
    }

    // remove the successfully completed task from the list
    lock (_syncLock)
        _pendingTasks.Remove(task);
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```cs
public Task ProcessAsync()
{
    QueueTaskAsync(SimulateWork());
}
```

The goal is to throw fatal exceptions (e.g., out-of-memory) immediately on the current thread's synchronization context, while task result/error processing is deferred until appropriate.

There's been an interesting discussion of using tasks with fire-and-forget [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22864367/1768303).

Answer (score 13):

You're close. It means that you can write it like this:

```
public Task ProcessAsync()
{
    // some sync code
    return SimulateWork();
}
```

That way you don't "pay" for the overhead of marking the method as `async` but you still keep the ability to await that whole operation.

Comment: @RoyiNamir if you're referring to `async void` event handlers, then they must stay `async` to support asynchronous operations, unlike `ProcessAsync` that can easily not be marked `async` without really changing anything.

Comment: Yes I know , jsut mentioned that they won't be able to have Task return type.

Comment: The important part to understand is that your void returning method will be non-awaitable as arnon mentioned. A user calling the code will not know if the method will run synchronously or asynchronously based on the `void` signature