# Endless async and await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I don´t understand something about async/await:

It is mandatory that an async method must have an await call inside... But if there is an await it is because it is calling another async method, right? So it seems to be an endless chain of async methods with awaits inside calling another async methods.

So is it possible to create a "first" async method, not calling any other async methods inside. Just create an async method because that method does a lot of work that could slow down the system.

Comment: "It is mandatory that an async method must have an await call inside..." No, it's the other way around: if you're using await inside a method, that method must be marked async. You can mark it async and not use an await (but that's usually incorrect)

Comment: @Dennis_E It's not *required* that an `async` method have an `await`, but there is almost never a sensible reason to do so, as the `async` would just be a lie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First, some clarifications

A method doesn't need an await to be `async`, it's the other way around. You can only use `await` in an `async` method. You *may* have a method that returns a `Task` without it being marked as `async`. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23383587/885318).

### Your actual question

IIUC, is about *"The Root Of All Async"*.
So, yes, it *is* possible to create a "first" `async` method. It's simply a method that returns a `Task` (or `Task<T>`).

There are two types of these tasks: [A Delegate Task and a Promise Task](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html).

1. A Delegate Task is fired by `Task.Run` (most times. `Task.StartNew` and `new Task(() => {});` are other options) and it has code to run. This is mostly used for offloading work.
2. A Promise Task is a `Task` that doesn't actually execute any code, it's only a mechanism to **a.** Wait to be notified upon completion *by* the `Task`. **b.** Signaling completion *using* the `Task`. This is done with [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) and is mostly used for inherently asynchronous operations (but also for [`async` synchronization objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock.aspx)) for example:

.

```
private static Task DoAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        tcs.SetResult(5);
    }).Start();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

These tools allow you to create those "roots", but unless you implement an `I/O` library (like `.Net`'s `DNS` class) or a synchronization object (like [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx)) yourself, you would rarely use them.

Comment: Thanks, your answer let me search more for TaskCompletionSource. To better understand it and when to use it, here is a StackOverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316613/real-life-scenarios-for-using-taskcompletionsourcet). It takes you to [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-8-Networking-835239c1/sourcecode?fileId=70769&pathId=221052408) code example.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `async` keyword is to simply allow the use of `await` inside the method, you don't *have* to call another `async` method internally e.g.

```
public async void WaitForSomething()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Right. A method being async is just an implementation detail. The thing you're awaiting is just an object (usually a Task) that implements the 'async pattern'.

Comment: Hmm 2 downvotes, care to elaborate? As far as I am aware my answer is technically accurate.

Comment: @James Assuming the OP isn't asking about the `async` keyword, but about asynchronous awaitable method calls then *"is it possible to create a "first" async method, not calling any other async methods inside?"* is about how to implement `Task.Delay`, not how to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are indeed ways of creating a `Task` besides using an `async` method.

- You can use the task constructor (although unless you have a particularly compelling reason to create a task that represents the execution of a delegate that you use before the delegate actually starts executing, you should really avoid doing this.  Just use the next option.
- You can use an existing method of `Task` to create tasks, such as `Task.Run` to represent the execution of a delegate in another thread, `Task.WhenAll` to represent the completion of a series of other tasks, `Task.FromAsync` to create a task based on a different pattern of asynchronous programming, etc.
- You can use a `TaskCompletionSource` to create a task that you complete whenever you want, allowing you to turn any inherently asynchronous behavior into a `Task`.  That inherently asynchronous operation could be an event firing, a callback method being called, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very intensive method which does a lot of work that could slow down the system, you can call it like this.

```
public async void CallerAsyncMethod()
{
    var taskResult = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IntensiveMethod());
    await taskResult;
}
```

Here `IntensiveMethod` is not an async method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this does not answer the question at all

Comment: @Morgoz needed to call a non-async method from an async method. This is the way it can be achieved. Please let me know where I am mistaken.

Comment: "It is mandatory that an async method must have an await call inside... " .... yours have one right at the end - so it's no counterexample (but the downvote is not from me - I was tempted though)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Well, its not for the downvote though... Learning is more important. I much emphasized on calling a non-async method.

Comment: yes but he asked if it's even possible to have one without *any* `await` and here your answer does not help at all

Comment: @CarstenKönig Well... you are right till an extent... ;) but as MorgoZ said "not calling any other async methods inside" I created IntensiveMethod() which is not an async method.

Comment: With `async-await` you should always use `Task.Run`.