# Returning from async method before locals are assigned

Tags: c#, async-await

This async method generates two CS0165 errors - Use of unassigned local variable.

```
public async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> DoWorkAsync(object[] objs)
{
    string msg;
    bool result;
    await Task.Run(() => result = _foo.DoWork(objs, out msg));
    return new Tuple<bool, string>(result, msg);
}
```

<s>Initially I was going to ask why, but now I'm pretty sure it's because an exception may be raised within the local Task.</s>

See magician Jon Skeet's comment below: the compiler doesn't know what Task.Run is doing, and cannot infer that the locals will be assigned.

So now I'll ask: what's the best way to implement this? Assign default values to the locals, create a local for the task and check task.IsFaulted before returning?

Should I generally propagate the exception? I suppose that's probably an unanswerable question depending on the context.

Comment: For starters, don't use `Task.Run` to fake async.

Comment: @i3arnon What do you mean 'fake' async? How do you implement a method at the bottom of an async chain? Maybe you have something beyond "that's not the right way" to add?

Comment: This is how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24539523/885318

Comment: It's not so much because an exception may be raised, as because the C# compiler doesn't know anything about what `Task.Run` does. That's just an arbitrary method as far as it's concerned.

Comment: And this explains why you shouldn't expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Comment: @i3arnon Thanks. Makes sense. I've learned these same various async/await constructs a dozen times.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't stop thinking about this point. Can the compiler not infer from the context of the anon method what will happen? Or perhaps it is a matter of the fact there is no contract saying that Task.Run is going to call that method?

Comment: @Michael: No, it can't. Imagine you were calling `Foo.Bar` there instead of `Task.Run` - do you think that should change things? Imagine that `Foo.Bar` was just a method returning a `Task<int>`, and never executed the delegate.

Comment: @i3arnon Wanted to say thanks again. Refactored the project I was working on and it is significantly cleaner and makes a lot more sense now.  Problems looking like nails, and all that.

Comment: @Michael sure, anytime :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the `Tuple` from your `Task.Run`, like so:

```
public Task<Tuple<bool, string>> DoWorkAsync(object[] objs)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        string msg;
        var result = _foo.DoWork(objs, out msg);
        return new Tuple<bool, string>(result, msg);
    });
}
```

Now you don't need to worry about uninitialized local variables.

Comment: Oh. Duh. That seems much cleaner.

Comment: But with this solution your method is no longer `async`. (Though you may not need it since you don't `await` anymore).

Comment: @RenéVogt it doesn't need to be to begin with. But it can still use async and await instead of a simple return.

Comment: @RenéVogt The `async` keyword has become redundant as we can just return the `Task` from `Task.Run` directly. If you wish you can still put the `async`/`await` keywords in, but you don't really gain and just lose in performance slightly.

Comment: Got it, and after updating my answer I realized it's almost exactly yours, so I deleted mine.

Comment: Thanks for the edification Lukazoid and @I3amon. I understand why your answer is preferable to mine although mine does work(?).  I know understand that by  assigning _foo.DoWork to a Task it will run asynchronously.