# Why do unawaited async methods not throw exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await

I thought that async methods were supposed to behave like normal methods until they arrived at an await.

Why does this not throw an exception?

Is there a way to have the exception thrown without awaiting?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t = new Test();
        t.Helper();
    }

    public async Task Helper()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a historical note, exceptions were originally raised "directly" as you expect. However, this behavior was confusing because exceptions before and after the `await` would behave differently, and it could get *really* confusing if the `await` was conditional.

Comment: @StephenCleary When was it changed? While in the CTP phase?

Comment: @I3arnon: Yes; IIRC only the first CTP behaved this way.

Comment: @Craig, one other option is to use `async void`, check ["Fire and Forget approach"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22864367/1768303).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An exception thrown inside an `async` method is, by design, stored inside the returned task. To get your hands on the exception you can:

1. `await` the task: `await t.Helper();`
2. `Wait` the task: `t.Helper().Wait();`
3. Check the task's `Exception` property **after** the task has been completed: `var task = t.Helper(); Log(task.Exception);`
4. Add a continuation to that task that handles the exception: `t.Helper().ContinueWith(t => Log(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);`

Your best option is the first one. Simply `await` the task and handle the exception (unless there's a specific reason you can't do that). More in [Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx)