# order of execution of Task

Tags: c#, async-await

Jon Skeet says

> The output shows *Fetched the task* before it fails. The exception has been thrown
> synchronously **before that output is written**, because there are no await expressions
> before the validation

Is there any guarantee about the fact *the exception has been thrown
synchronously **before that output is written*** ?

Why cannot be the output text(*Fetched the task*) written out at first?

```
async Task Main()
{
    Task<int> task = ComputeLengthAsync(null);
    Console.WriteLine("Fetched the task");
    int length = await task;
    Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
}

static async Task<int> ComputeLengthAsync(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    }
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return text.Length;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441859/3034273

Comment: Please link to the broader context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any guarantee about the fact the exception has been thrown synchronously before that output is written ?

Yes. [`async` methods begin executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). In fact, if there is no `await` in the method at all, then the compiler will warn you that the entire method will run synchronously.

> Why cannot be the output text(Fetched the task) written out at first?

The output *is* written out. The exception is not thrown directly; since it is thrown in an `async` method, the exception is captured and placed on the returned task. Then when the `await task;` line is run, the `await` retrieves the exception from the task and (re-)throws it.