# why exception not moving to Main method for my list of task

Tags: c#, task

Below is the `Main` method code,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task<bool>>();

        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                taskList.Add(Processor.Process(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And the `Process` method,

```
public static class Processor
{
    public static async Task<bool> Process(int num)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write(num);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Hello Exception");
        }

        await Task.Delay(1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output of the program is `02468`. I have 2 questions,

1. Why the exception not delegating to `Main` method in case of odd number according to the code?
2. With above code my thought that `task` is just added and it will not go for processing until I use something like `var responses = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);`, but I noticed it's processing, why is this nature, can we hold processing and instructing at once?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Until `await Task.Delay(1);` your task is running synchronously on the same thread as your `for` loop. Slight simplification, but: when it hits the `await` it will suspend the processing and return to `Main` to evaluate `taskList.Add`. I believe at that stage exceptions are still wrapped up in a `Task` though. I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar. so this means still the processing is not complete and it's in evaluate state `taskList.Add`, then why I get result for 0,2,4, etc

Comment: Because that's executed on the same thread as your `for` loop _before_ the task is returned.

Comment: Related to your first question: [Why do unawaited async methods not throw exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441790/why-do-unawaited-async-methods-not-throw-exceptions) Related to your second question: [Enforce an async method to be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [compiler generated code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4CsA3IYRgMzk5LlakAKUEYMAzn2iEA3oQCQjZqwwAOckgA8wCBAA2APk7deAgBQBLAHYAXUoYCuAWwCU40QTFj9AM1K6Ll0gFJS7ALx+pMS2DmL2jhI4AJzuVta0oQC+4mIwqnwwKeGOxgAW3ADuZjBFAKIIvAAOxvoQhroARAASaaoQpOVVNXUN8SnJoRhR8gB0ACJpAIYAnro4fQSkS6QSAOykxlDmMAliA4lAA===), you will find:

1. In the `MoveNext` method, exception is catched and saved in `<>t__builder`.
   You may also notice `await Task.Delay(1)` is converted to `awaiter = Task.Delay(1).GetAwaiter()`, and `awaiter.GetResult()` will automatically check `Task.Exception` for you, that's why awaiting a task will throw exception.
2. When `Processor.Process` is invoked, it will call `<>t__builder.Start` to start the task, so you don't need something like `await`.
   To hold processing a task you can use [Task's constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-ctor(system-action)) to create one and use `Start` method to run it.

```
public static class Processor
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private struct <Process>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        public int <>1__state;

        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder;

        public int num;

        private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

        private void MoveNext()
        {
            int num = <>1__state;
            bool result;
            try
            {
                TaskAwaiter awaiter;
                if (num != 0)
                {
                    if (this.num % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Hello Exception");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(this.num);
                    awaiter = Task.Delay(1).GetAwaiter();
                    if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        num = (<>1__state = 0);
                        <>u__1 = awaiter;
                        <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    awaiter = <>u__1;
                    <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                    num = (<>1__state = -1);
                }
                awaiter.GetResult();
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                <>1__state = -2;
                <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
        }

        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
            this.MoveNext();
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
            <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
        }

        void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
            //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
            this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
        }
    }

    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<Process>d__0))]
    public static Task<bool> Process(int num)
    {
        <Process>d__0 stateMachine = default(<Process>d__0);
        stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Create();
        stateMachine.num = num;
        stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
        stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
        return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate your reply @shingo