# Running a Task in the background (PCL)

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I have a class with an `async` method:

```
public static async Task GetData() { ... }
```

In the app framework I am using I need to start that process and forget about it when the app starts:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    await MyService.GetData();
}
```

I can't make `OnStart` `async.` How do I start it in a background task and forget about it?

Comment: Tasks run on background threads. What are you asking? Does `GetData` do a lot of synchronous processing before starting the asynchronous part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fire this `async` operation and forget about it all you need to do is invoke the method without awaiting the returned task:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    MyService.GetDataAsync();
}
```

However, since you're not observing the task you would never know if it completed successfully.

You should either keep a reference to the task and `await` it in a later time:

```
public Task _dataTask;
protected override void OnStart()
{
    _dataTask = MyService.GetDataAsync();
}

public Task AwaitInitializationAsync()
{
    return _dataTask;
}
```

Or add a continuation handling any exceptions:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    MyService.GetDataAsync().ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        try 
        { 
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exceptions
        }
    });
}
```

You shouldn't use `Task.Run` as [Noseratio explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28259686/885318), however using `async void` is much worse since an exception in an `async void` method (which isn't a UI event handler) would **tear down the entire process***.

You can try to make the method `async void` while making sure there won't be any exceptions thrown inside it with a `try-catch` block:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    try
    {
        await GetData(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle e.
    }
}
```

But I would still recommend against it since even the chance of a complete crash is dangerous.

---

<sup>*You can get around that by registering an even handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` but this should be a last resort, not a best practice</sup>

Comment: Whether the OP wants to handle exceptions, or tear down the process, is up to him, see the comment to my answer. The least desirable behavior is to ignore exceptions of fire-and-forget tasks, which was my point. That said, if he does want to handle them, why use `ContinueWith` and not just `async void` with `await` inside `try/catch` inside?

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257772/c-sharp-running-a-task-in-the-background-pcl#comment44923620_28259686)

Comment: Good to see you made an edit. I can hardly think of any use cases where `ContinueWith` would give any advantage over or couldn't be replaced with `async/await`. Especially, keeping in mind implications with error handling in continuations.

Comment: @Noseratio I, of course, have no problem with `async-await` but `async void` was meant for UI event handlers and should generally be discouraged elsewhere.

Comment: I'd say, not only UI event handlers, but any kind of event handlers. Personally, I don't think it's a dogma. I also use it for `On`-like overridable notifications like the OP's `OnStart` and for fire-and-forget tasks as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22864367/1768303).

Comment: @Noseratio well, not really. Since in other kinds of event handlers you don't necessarily have a `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: I don't see why `SynchronizationContext` is relevant here. If there's none, exceptions from `async void` will still be thrown asynchronously on `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @Noseratio That's exactly the point. That's what crashes the application. There's no difference between SC-less event handlers and just regular methods.

Comment: *There's no difference between SC-less event handlers and just regular methods* - Hmm, I don't understand this. Indeed, there's no difference between event handlers and regular methods on a thread without SC. As much as on a thread with SC. Event handler *is* a just regular method, it only has special signature - and only by convention. There's no special treatment given by C# or CLR to "event handler" methods. If a method is `async void`, the unhandled exception will crash the app regardless of SC, unless there is a global handler like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

Comment: @Noseratio The difference is that when there's an SC the exception is posted to it, and the decision whether to crash or not is left to the SC ([here, for example, is an SC that handles exceptions instead of crashing](http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/)). When you don't have an SC you have no choice but to crash.

Comment: I appreciate how you care about `SynchronizationContext` here. You may want to change your `ContinueWith` solution to take this into account, too. As is, your error handling logic would run on `ThreadPool` rather than on the original SC.

Comment: @Noseratio 1. I don't. I care about not crashing my application. 2. There's no SC to begin with. 3. What's the point of using the SC? The goal  is not to let the exception be unhandled and `ContinueWith` does that with a `try-catch` block. What would the SC add?

Answer (score 4):

> I can't make OnStart Async. How do I start it in a background task and
>   forget about it?

Why not? Nothing prevents you from making it `async`. The `async` modifier doesn't affect the CLR method signature, i.e., you can override a `void` method and make it `async`:

```
abstract class AppBase
{
    protected abstract void OnStart();
}

class App: AppBase
{
    public static async Task GetData() { await Task.Delay(1); }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        await GetData(); 
    }
}
```

**This way, at least you'll see an exception if `GetData` throws, unlike what the other answer suggests.**

Make sure you understand how `async void` methods and `Task` error handling work in general, [this material](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161/1768303) may be helpful.

Some other problems with `Task.Run( () => MyService.GetData() )`:

- as `GetData` is *already* asynchronous, there's very little sense in wrapping it with `Task.Run`. It's usually only done in a client-side UI app and only if `GetData` has a long-running synchronous part (before it hits its 1st `await`). Otherwise, you might as well just call `GetData()` without `Task.Run` and without `await` (which also would be a bad idea: in either case, you'd be doing a fire-and-forget call without observing possible exceptions).
- `Task.Run` will start `GetData` on a random pool thread without synchronization content, which may be a problem for either a UI app or an ASP.NET app.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea (here is [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28284243/885318))

Comment: Why `await` it when you don't care when it finishes?  Just invoke the method and ignore the `Task`.

Comment: @l3arnon, there is a link in my answer which goes into details about how `async void` methods work, including exceptions. Whether the OP wants to handle exceptions here (see Eric Lippert's [Vexing exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx)) or whether he wants to crash the process is up to him. The point is the exceptions wouldn't go unnoticed.

Comment: @Servy, see my comment above. For a more detailed discussion, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22864367/1768303).

Comment: @Noseratio The least desirable behavior is indeed to ignore exceptions, and just above it is to tear down the entire process. There are many ways to not ignore exceptions: 2 events, `try-catch` inside, continuations and crashing is the least pleasant and the most dangerous.

Comment: @l3arnon, feel free to down-vote if you really think what I wrote is a bad idea. I won't retaliate :)