# Will the call to the last awaited method be optimized to never return INTO the method if there is nothing after it?

Tags: c#, async-await

Here's the method:

```
async (a) =>
{
await DoSomethingForTheFirstTimeAsync();
await DoSomethingForTheSecondTimeAsync();
await DoSomethingForTheLastTimeAsync();
}
```

The question is: "Will we get back to the method after the last call finishes it's work?" I fail to see any scenario where it should be needed.

Comment: If you don't need to get back to the previous context, then don't use await

Comment: My understanding is that it will still return and then exit the method. Why are you asking? It should make no difference to any app you are building. Also take a look at this post around the use of void async methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft the existence of the method keeps local roots alive. I don't really have a problem with it. Asked mostly because I'm curious and couldn't find an answer if there are some specific optimizations or not.

Comment: @MatiasCicero strange remark. I may want to get back to the flow, but not the context.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Getting back to the flow is getting back to the previous context

Comment: Take a look here for a fire and forget pattern, it seems this may be what you really need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864367/fire-and-forget-approach

Comment: @Murray thanks, I know the pattern though^^ As I said it's more of curiosity then an actual problem. I've cleaned the roots manually. My real await actions are similar and should be awaited. it's just the fact that I don't really care for the last one, so I was curious whether or not it will hold some memory until done.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov, you are awaiting the last one, so yes, the flow will wait for the last one to end, but not in a blocking manner. If you really just want to fire and forget, call your last method without the await.

Comment: @MatiasCicero then it will execute synchronously and I'll be waiting for it to finish. maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @MatiasCicero also the same flow doesn't necessarily mean the same synchronization context.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov if you remove the await on that method then it won't execute synchronously, please read the documentation.

Comment: @MatiasCicero ah, I misunderstood you, you mean suppress the warnings and call it without await. I thought about tasks, which would make the call synchronous, if I want to get exceptions back. Yeap, that would do the trick. Now I'm gonna test what happens with exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the scenarios where it is needed is when the last method throws an exception.  Await will throw in the context of the calling method.

You may set a breakpoint on the closing brace in the method - thus, the last call returns.

Comment: Or it will throw in some other context, if I'm not forcing the usage of persistent context. I thought about it but it does not really matter whether the exception is thrown inside or already outside of the method.